# Google visualization addListener called function reference error

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, dom-events

I am attempting to handle a select event for a chart, I want to know which row/column has been selected, but the called function I get an error:

> Uncaught Reference Error: chart is not defined.

The code is very nearly what is in the example [for the pie chart](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#pie_chart), and the [select event handler](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#select_event). I expect I need to have the chart object be known globally, but am not sure how to do it.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     11],
          ['Eat',      2],
          ['Sleep',    12]
        ]);
        var options = { title: 'My Daily Activities' };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);
      }
      function selectHandler() {
          var selection = visualization.getSelection();
          alert("it");
      }



    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever solve this? If not ...

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

//declare your variables in the global scope
var chart, data;

function drawChart() {
    data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
        ['Work',     11],
        ['Eat',      2],
        ['Sleep',    12]
    ]);
    var options = { title: 'My Daily Activities' };

    chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);
}

function selectHandler() {
    //"visualization.getSelection();" dos not exist
    //access the global variable chart and its current selection
    var selection = chart.getSelection();
    alert(data.getValue(selection[0].row, 1));
}
```

...Alerts 11, 2 or 12.

see fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/7e6Va/**

Comment: Im also facing same issue.: Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

Comment: @STEEL, the error you are experiencing is most likely because you are not including the google loader `<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>`, or tries to access the google object before it is loaded. But hard to teel without seeing the code.

Comment: Hi, i figured it out. It was due to my AJAX DOM elements. since map was in my AJAX. I went ahead with highchartsJS. Google charts doesnt work fine with AJAX loaded content